# Ktor Server Testing

Tags: testing, ktor, koin

I have an ktor application with structure like that:

1. Main logic incapsulated in controllers, which have interfaces. Ex

```
interface AuthController {
   suspend fun authenticate(request: Request): Response

   suspend fun registration(request: Request): Response

   suspend fun refreshToken(request: Request): Response
}
```

And implementation, which has some injects of `DAO` and others.

```
class AuthControllerImpl : AuthController, KoinComponent {

   private val authDao by inject<AdminsDao>()
   private val tokensDao by inject<TokensDao>()
   private val jwtProvider by inject<JwtProvider>()
   //override methods
}
```

2. Controllers injects into routes. Ex

```
fun Route.auth(
   basePath: String
) {
   val authController by inject<AuthController>()
   //post, get, etc
}
```

3. Routes calls into Application modules

I'm using KOIN as Service Locator and i can mock `DAO` and other things, which injects into controllers. The question is — can i make different scopes to use one controller implementation in prodaction with real `DAO` and with mock in test module?
I can use only controllers interfaces in test module, but if i change the implementation in prod and accidentally broke anything, it wouldn't affect the tests.

Answer (score 0):

Just make a new Koin module in Ktor `testApplication` with mocked data source interface implementations